# show row information in textview Android

Tags: android, json, listview, textview

I have a listView in my fist screen that I show the information in each row from json , when I click on each item, I have another listView with new information and textview in the same page, I want to show the pervious list view row in text view,

would you please let me know how can I implement this,

Thanks in advance!

here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="######">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/no_message"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
        android:gravity="center"></TextView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my onItemClick :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    chooseTest(testIds.get(position));

    String selectedTestId = testIds.get(position);

    Helpers.saveToSharedPreferences(getActivity(),
            Constants_Prefs.SELECTED_TOP_LEVEL_RECORD,
            Constants_Keys.SELECTED_TEST_ID,
            selectedTestId);

    FormTypeListFragment passDataTo = new FormTypeListFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("DATA", selectedTestId);

    passDataTo.setArguments(bundle);



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you added onItemClick to your question, now all you need to do is access data from bundle in your FormTypeListFragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // init layout
    TextView listTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_textview);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
       String selectedTestId = bundle.getString("DATA");
       listTextView.setText(selectedTestId);
    }
}
```